# Do function declarations in the middle of a function slow down performance?

Tags: python

Example of what I'm asking about:

```
def foo(bar):
    """Do a print function bar times"""
    count = 0
    while count < bar:
        def baz():
            return "This is baz"
        print(baz())
        count += 1
```

Does the function declaration in the middle of the `while` loop slow down the execution time of `foo`?

Comment: Yes.  Compared to declaring it once outside of the for-loop, it will be slower.

Comment: ... especially inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on one of the comments, you are adding additional work to your loop. Every time you declare `baz()` the compile is doing work and allocating memory. Is there any particular reason you wanted to do it this way?

More efficient code:

```
def foo(bar):
    """Do a print function bar times"""
    count = 0
    def baz():
       return "This is baz"
    while count < bar:
        print(baz())
        count += 1
```

Most efficient code:

```
def baz():
    return "This is baz"
def foo(bar):
    """Do a print function bar times"""
    count = 0
    while count < bar:
        print(baz())
        count += 1
```

Comment: Not really. I just wanted to see if there was any inefficiency associated with defining a function inside of another function or a loop.